# Selecting an Option in an HTML Select

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML select with several options. One of them is selected by default, but I would like to be able to change which one is selected. I found out how to do it using javascript, but I would like to do it using PHP as the information used to set it is stored in a PHP `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: could you show the html code? also the js way you found - and your php code so we can help you?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the data is stored in $`_SESSION['data']`, then you can set the `selected` attribute.

```
<select name="dropdown">
  <option> <?php if ($_SESSION['data'] == "test"){ echo " selected "} ?> value="test">
   test
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>
    <option<?php if($condition_one)   print 'selected'; ?>>One</option>
    <option<?php if($condition_two)   print 'selected'; ?>>Two</option>
    <option<?php if($condition_three) print 'selected'; ?>>Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to learn PHP, I recommend starting here.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Start Googling around for PHP tutorials.  After you learn basic PHP, this will be easy for you.